# Save Element of html page as image format

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, html5-canvas

having a webpage where on div (a square box) which will be used to drag and drop image icons write some text change background color , I want to make that div after dropping elements saved as jpg, bmp format.

Can somebody help me how to do it, using ASP.net C#?

i tried and used canvas but that doesn't work, it only save the div (square box) with white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done easily with canvas with some of the library like html2canvas. I have done something similar in one of the project long back where I was capturing SVG object under div and on run time i was getting around 10-15 SVG object on the page and was able to capture each one on any given point of time.

I'm not sure this in asp.net and C# but its possible in HTML5 with html2canvas.

Comment: Ankit, it can be done using canvas but the problem is i am using jquery drag and drop to place item on canvas so when saving as image.. the canvas become blank. do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't know why you want to drop something directly on canvas. Canvas is not made for that. Canvas is more like a layer which allows you to draw something on that. More ever you can do something like this. create first canvas and top of that create a div which hold drag-able items for you and once user done ask him to click on some button "Save" and then marge this canvas with the div objects which user drop. Directly you can't draw and drop the objects on canvas. you can see this example which i created for you to explain who div works with draggable object http://jsbin.com/ikide/1/edit